# How do I add an event to a Kendo UI Scheduler?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

we have been trying to get the kendo scheduler working with signalr to create a realtime scheduler, are are able to successfully update the kendo console which now works for all clients connected to the scheduler. our trouble now is adding the event manually with javascript. here is our example:

```
var notificationHub = $.connection.MyBookingHub;

notificationHub.client.Notify = function (MyStart, MyEnd, MyMessage) {
    kendoConsole.log(kendo.toString(new Date(MyStart) + " " + new Date(MyEnd) + " " + MyMessage));

    //this is where we are doing something wrong as we get an error regarding the "set" property
    e.events.set("start", new Date(MyStart));
    e.events.set("end", new Date(MyEnd));
    e.events.set("title", MyMessage);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code snippet, I can't tell what you expect the `e` variable to be. It looks like you may be confusing the [technical events](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#events) of the widget with the conceptual event data which is displayed with the scheduler widget.

Here's [one way](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#fields-dataSource) to add an event to an existing scheduler widget (using the [DataSource.add](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-add) method):

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.dataSource.add( {
  start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
  end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
  title: "Interview"
});
```

You would only use the [ObservableObject.set method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observableobject#methods-set) on existing models.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply i had to make another question as i have to wait 8 hours before i could reply to question.. rrr

Comment: [link to related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542086/how-do-i-update-a-kendo-scheduler-from-a-signalr-hub-method)