# How do I update a Kendo scheduler from a SignalR hub method?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-scheduler

Here is the code using signalr, it successfully sends the information to the hub and the hub is just doing a clients.all.Notifiy etc etc..... I've just add the code sample that you recommedend, i doing this from the scheduler_change(e) so that on a single click it will insert the info that is returned from the hub.. for some reason the new booking does not show on the scheduler.

```
 function scheduler_change(e) {
        var start = e.start; //selection start date
        var end = e.end; //selection end date
        var slots = e.slots; //list of selected slots
        var events = e.events; //list of selected Scheduler events


        var notificationHub = $.connection.MyBookingHub;
        notificationHub.client.Notify = function (MyStart, MyEnd, MyMessage) {

       //     kendoConsole.log(kendo.toString(new Date(MyStart) + " " + new Date(MyEnd) + " " + MyMessage));


            var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler", function () {
                scheduler.dataSource.add({
                    start: new Date(MyStart),
                    end: new Date(MyEnd),
                    title: "Costas Interview"
                });
           });

        };


        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            notificationHub.server.sendNotification(start, end, "Booking Title");

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only create the `client.notify` method once, not each time the change event on the scheduler widget is triggered. Same goes for starting the connection.

So it should probably be something like:

```
// set up hub methods and start connection ..
var notificationHub = $.connection.MyBookingHub;
notificationHub.client.Notify = function (MyStart, MyEnd, MyMessage) {
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    scheduler.dataSource.add({
        start: new Date(MyStart),
        end: new Date(MyEnd),
        title: "Costas Interview"
    });
};

window.hubConnection = $.connection.hub.start();

// create scheduler change handler
function scheduler_change(e) {
    var start = e.start; //selection start date
    var end = e.end; //selection end date
    var slots = e.slots; //list of selected slots
    var events = e.events; //list of selected Scheduler events

    window.hubConnection.done(function () {
        notificationHub.server.sendNotification(start, end, "Booking Title");
    });
}
```